# add bar button item programmatically at ViewControllers after rootView Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a View hierarchy

there is just one navigation controller and its rootViewController.

I want to add a left bar button item at the view which is circled.

the View I want to add barButton:

[image]

I tried

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
```

in `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillAppear()` but none of them worked out. 
I also tried adding `UINavigationItem` in storyBoard and then adding barButtonItem. this didn't work too.

**EDIT**

I tried the answers below and that's what I get in the output.

my output after trying answers:

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code used for defining `editButtonItem`.

Comment: it's something built in.

Comment: @DávidPásztor this is the definition provided by xcode     var editButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem { get }
Description 
Returns a bar button item that toggles its title and associated state between Edit and Done.
If one of the custom views of the navigationItem property is set to the returned object, the associated navigation bar displays an Edit button if isEditing is false and a Done button if isEditing is true. The default button action invokes the setEditing(_:animated:) method.
Availability iOS (10.0 and later), tvOS (10.0 and later)
Declared In UIKit

Answer (score 1):

You can add Bar Button like

```
let btnleft : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:35, height:35))
btnleft.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
btnleft.contentMode = .left

btnleft.setImage(UIImage(named :"yourimage.png"), for: .normal)
            btnleft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YOUR_ACTION), for: .touchDown)
let backBarButon: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnleft)

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([backBarButon], animated: false)
```

Comment: check if your back button is not hidden

Comment: no, i have the back button. I want to insert a right button

Comment: self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([backBarButon], animated: false)

Answer (score 0):

**a)**  Make a new **BarButtonItem** with `System Item` , `Target View Controller Instance` and `Action Method Name`.

**b)** Assign it to `leftBarButtonItem`

**c)** Good to do this in `func viewWillAppear()`

And thats it !

```
let editButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(actionEdit)) // actionEdit is your Action Method for this button
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
```

Comment: I think the problem is not the button but the navigation bar it self. I tried every kind of buttons but it still won't show up